# Read CSV file using kafka-connect and sink into ms sql database?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am working on POC, I have to read csv file and insert it into ms sql server.
I have created below configuration But I am getting below excpetion:

**)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Value schema must be of type Struct**

**Configuration is as below:**

**1. Sample csv file data:**

```
id,record1,record2,record3,created

1,1772056014794065487,160842,20668578,9999-12-31

2,1772056014794065487,160842,20668578,9999-12-31

3,1772056014794065487,160842,20668578,9999-12-31

4,1772056014794065487,160842,20668578,9999-12-31

5,1772056014794065487,160842,20668578,9999-12-31
```

**2. file-source-connector**

```
{"name":"file-source",

"config":
         {
          "connector.class":"FileStreamSource",
          "tasks.max":"1",
          "file":"/tmp/my-connect-test.dat",
          "topic":"connect-test",
          "name":"file-source"},
          "tasks":[{"connector":"file-source","task":0}],
          "type":"source"}
```

**3. jdbc-sink-connector:**

```
{"name":"test-sink",
  "config":   {
         "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
         "tasks.max":"1",
         "topics":"connect-test",
         "topic.prefix":"connect-test", 
         "insert.mode":"insert",
         "table.name.format":"dz.temp_data",
         "pk.mode":"record_value",
         "pk.fields":"id",
         "incrementing.column.name":"id",
         "table.whitelist":"dz.temp_data",
         "mode":"incrementing",
         "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
         "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
         "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
         "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
         "key.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081",
         "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost8081",
         "connection.url":"jdbc:sqlserver://**;databaseName=**;username=**;password=***",
         "name":"test-sink"},
         "tasks":[{"connector":"test-sink","task":0}],
         "type":"sink"}
```

**4. ms sql table:**

```
CREATE TABLE dz.temp_data (
  id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  record1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   record2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
record3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
record4 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
created VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

If I Test topic by avro consumer, i am getting correct output.

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic connect-test --from-beginning
```

But I am getting exception while inserting into ms sql database.

Kindly help with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the JDBC Sink, you have to have a schema. CSV files do not have a schema. Therefore, you will need to define one along the way.

To understand more about serialisation and schemas see [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/).

You have a couple of options here:

1. Use a connector that can apply the schema at ingest (e.g. [kafka-connect-spooldir](https://www.confluent.io/hub/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir)). If you do this make sure that you use AvroConverter or JSONConverter with `schemas.enable=true` for your value.converter in the Kafka Connect source configuration. You can see an example of this in action [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-in-action-enriching-csv-events-with-data-from-rdbms-into-aws/).
2. Use [ksqlDB](https://ksqldb.io) to apply your schema and then reserialise the data to a different topic in a more appropriate format (e.g. Avro), and use that topic to populate the database. For example:

   ```
   -- Declare a schema for the existing topic
   CREATE STREAM SOURCE_DATA (id INT, record1 VARCHAR, record2 VARCHAR, record3 VARCHAR, 
                              record4 VARCHAR, record5 VARCHAR) 
                 WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='connect-test', VALUE_FORMAT='DELIMITED');

   -- Write a new Kafka topic that serialises all the data 
   -- from the first topic to a new one, in Avro
   CREATE STREAM SOURCE_DATA_RESERIALISED WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='connect-test_avro',
                                                VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS 
     SELECT * FROM SOURCE_DATA;
   ```

Comment: I tried with option 2. file-source-connector did not worked. So i provided csv file to kafka-console-producer. `kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic connect-test < /tmp/my-connect-test.dat`

Comment: i tried with pipe separated file, but seems its not possible in confluent 5.3.1, then i updated confluent to 5.4.1 , there is option of vlue_delimiter so i used  `Create stream sample {column1 string, column2 string } WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='SampleData', VALUE_FORMAT='DELIMITED', VALUE_DELIMITER='|');`   but its gave excpetion while converting DELIMITED stream to AVRO format. CREATE STREAM sample_avro WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='SampleDataAvro', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', VALUE_DELIMITER='|') AS SELECT * FROM sample_delimited`;  for this line getting exception 'Delimeter only supported with DELIMITED format'

Comment: Start a new question, with full details, and I will answer it there :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60631130/read-pipe-separated-value-file-using-kafka-connect-and-sink-into-ms-sql-database