# Read pipe separated values in ksql

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am working on POC, I have to read pipe separated value file and insert these records into ms sql server.
I am using confluent 5.4.1 to use `value_delimiter` create stream property. But its giving exception: `Delimeter only supported with DELIMITED format`

**1. Start Confluent  (version: 5.4.1)::**

```
[Dev root @ myip ~]
# confluent local start
    The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment
    only, NOT for production usage. https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /tmp/confluent.vHhSRAnj
Starting zookeeper
zookeeper is [UP]
Starting kafka
kafka is [UP]
Starting schema-registry
schema-registry is [UP]
Starting kafka-rest
kafka-rest is [UP]
Starting connect
connect is [UP]
Starting ksql-server
ksql-server is [UP]
Starting control-center
control-center is [UP]
[Dev root @ myip ~]
# jps
49923 KafkaRestMain
50099 ConnectDistributed
49301 QuorumPeerMain
50805 KsqlServerMain
49414 SupportedKafka
52103 Jps
51020 ControlCenter
1741
49646 SchemaRegistryMain
[Dev root @ myip ~]
#
```

**2. Create Topic:**

```
[Dev root @ myip ~]
# kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic SampleData
Created topic SampleData.
```

**3. Provide pipe separated data to SampeData Topic**

```
[Dev root @ myip ~]
# kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic SampleData <<EOF
> this is col1|and now col2|and col 3 :)
> EOF
>>[Dev root @ myip ~]
#
```

**4. Start KSQL::**

```
[Dev root @ myip ~]
# ksql

                  ===========================================
                  =        _  __ _____  ____  _             =
                  =       | |/ // ____|/ __ \| |            =
                  =       | ' /| (___ | |  | | |            =
                  =       |  <  \___ \| |  | | |            =
                  =       | . \ ____) | |__| | |____        =
                  =       |_|\_\_____/ \___\_\______|       =
                  =                                         =
                  =  Streaming SQL Engine for Apache Kafka® =
                  ===========================================

Copyright 2017-2019 Confluent Inc.

CLI v5.4.1, Server v5.4.1 located at http://localhost:8088

Having trouble? Type 'help' (case-insensitive) for a rundown of how things work!
```

**5. Declare a schema for the existing topic: SampleData**

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM sample_delimited (
>       column1 varchar(1000),
>       column2 varchar(1000),
>       column3 varchar(1000))
>       WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='SampleData', VALUE_FORMAT='DELIMITED', VALUE_DELIMITER='|');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------
```

**6. Verify data into KSQl Stream**

```
ksql>  SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' to 'earliest'. Use the UNSET command to revert your change.
ksql> SELECT * FROM sample_delimited emit changes limit 1;
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|ROWTIME                    |ROWKEY                     |COLUMN1                    |COLUMN2                    |COLUMN3                    |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|1584339233947              |null                       |this is col1               |and now col2               |and col 3 :)               |
Limit Reached
Query terminated
```

**7. Write a new Kafka topic: SampleDataAvro that serializes all the data from sample_delimited stream to Avro format stream**

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM sample_avro WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='SampleDataAvro', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS SELECT * FROM sample_delimited;
Delimeter only supported with DELIMITED format
ksql>
```

***8. Above line gives exception::***

`Delimeter only supported with DELIMITED format`

**9. Load ms sql kafka connect configuration**

`confluent local load test-sink -- -d ./etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-quickstart-mssql.properties`

Answer (score 0):

The only time you need to specify the delimiter is when you define the stream that is *reading* from the *source* topic.

Here's my worked example:

1. Populate a topic with pipe-delimited data:

   ```
   $ kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -t SampleData -P<<EOF
   this is col1|and now col2|and col 3 :)
   EOF
   ```
2. Declare a stream over it

   ```sql
   CREATE STREAM sample_delimited ( 
           column1 varchar(1000),
           column2 varchar(1000),
           column3 varchar(1000)) 
           WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='SampleData', VALUE_FORMAT='DELIMITED', VALUE_DELIMITER='|');
   ```
3. Query the stream to make sure it works

   ```sql
   ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
   Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' to 'earliest'. Use the UNSET command to revert your change.

   ksql> SELECT * FROM sample_delimited emit changes limit 1;
   +----------------+--------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
   |ROWTIME         |ROWKEY  |COLUMN1        |COLUMN2       |COLUMN3       |
   +----------------+--------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
   |1583933584658   |null    |this is col1   |and now col2  |and col 3 :)  |
   Limit Reached
   Query terminated
   ```
4. Reserialise the data to Avro:

   ```sql
   CREATE STREAM sample_avro WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='SampleDataAvro', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS SELECT * FROM sample_delimited;
   ```
5. Dump the contents of the topic - note that it is now Avro:

   ```sql
   ksql> print SampleDataAvro;
   Key format: UNDEFINED
   Value format: AVRO
   rowtime: 3/11/20 1:33:04 PM UTC, key: <null>, value: {"COLUMN1": "this is col1", "COLUMN2": "and now col2", "COLUMN3": "and col 3 :)"}
   ```

---

The error that you're hitting is as a result of bug [#4200](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/4200). You can wait for the next release of Confluent Platform, or use [standalone ksqlDB](https://ksqldb.io) in which the issue is already fixed.

Here's using ksqlDB 0.7.1 streaming the data to MS SQL:

```sql
CREATE SINK CONNECTOR SINK_MSSQL WITH (
    'connector.class'     = 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector',
    'connection.url'      = 'jdbc:sqlserver://mssql:1433',
    'connection.user'     = 'sa',
    'connection.password' = 'Admin123',
    'topics'              = 'SampleDataAvro',
    'key.converter'       = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter',
    'auto.create'         = 'true',
    'insert.mode'         = 'insert'
  );
```

Now query the data in MS SQL

```sql
1> Select @@version
2> go

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU17) (KB4515579) - 14.0.3238.1 (X64)
        Sep 13 2019 15:49:57
        Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
        Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS)

(1 rows affected)
```

```sql
1> SELECT * FROM SampleDataAvro;
2> GO
COLUMN3        COLUMN2         COLUMN1     
-------------- --------------- ------------------
and col 3 :)   and now col2    this is col1

(1 rows affected)
```

Comment: i am still getting error `ksql> CREATE STREAM sample_avro WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='SampleDataAvro', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO') AS SELECT * FROM sample_delimited;
Delimeter only supported with DELIMITED format
`

Comment: I am using, `Copyright 2017-2019 Confluent Inc. CLI v5.4.1, Server v5.4.1 located at localhost:8088`

Comment: This is different from what's in your question. Can you edit your question and append to it the full output of your session showing the `create stream` and subsequent `create stream as select` with error?

Comment: I have updated my question with full output on console. Basically i am **trying to Read pipe separated values file and sink into ms sql database.**

Comment: I've amended my answer